# How to keep 3 fixed width items in first row with 2 fixed width item in next row by vertically centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.content{
  border:1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item.second{
  margin:0 34.7%;
}

.item.fourth{
  margin-left: calc(100%-50px) /*not works */
}

.item.fifth{
  margin-right: calc(100%-50px) /*not works */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep the 3 items in the top row as well 2 items in the bottom row. top row justified with `space-between` that's correct. how to keep second row with `space-around`? it's all fixed width.

[here live demo:](https://plnkr.co/edit/p30Z0xPSOGRTGjAl?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Result expected :

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. External links are fine but only if the code is also included here. External links can break of change over time making the question invalid and not useful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `justify-content: space-between` to  `justify-content: space-around;` since for sure you will have 3 items in the first row (as I understand). Then you can just apply this property and it will only affect the second row since there is space. I also made a slight change to your HTML to make the code more responsive.

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.inner {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">5</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what you may want to do. with fixed width.

[image]

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.inner {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 15px auto;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">5</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.item{
   width: calc(33% - 10%); /* margin left and right*/
   max-width: calc(33% - 10%); /* margin left and right*/
   margin:5%;
}
```

And add `justify-content: center;` to **content** class.

```css
.content{
  border:1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item{
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(33% - 10%); /* margin left and right*/
  max-width: calc(33% - 10%); /* margin left and right*/
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```